# See a users permissions (all group memberships)

Tags: permissions, groups, membership

This seems like a silly question, but I can't find the solution myself and not on the web.

I need to find out which groups a user is a member of. (Similar to the "Member Of" tab in active directory) Where can I find that?

P.S. I'm trying to solve a more general issue, that how can I find out what a certain user has access to. I'm trying to grant permissions only through groups to solve this, but I couldn't find group memberships either. Any other ways I can achieve this?

Note that my scope is only one site collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below mentioned script. This will list user with all its memebership.

```
$user = Get-SPUser -Web https://http://server/sites/yoursite |  Where{$_.LoginName -LIKE "*|domain\user"}

$User

Get-SPSite http://server/sites/yoursite  -Limit All | Select -ExpandProperty RootWeb | Select -ExpandProperty SiteUsers | Where {user.UserLogin -EQ $_.LoginName } |Select -ExpandProperty Groups |Select Name, {$_.ParentWeb.Url}
```

Here is the nice blog related to users:
[Exploring SharePoint Users, Groups, and Security Using PowerShell](http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint-2013/exploring-sharepoint-users-groups-and-security-using-powershell)

You have to update the two things

- replace domain\user with your user name
- `http://server/sites/yoursit`e with url of your site collection